# Second form submit button seems to be skipped(?) PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html

I need help about this, I have a PHP page, which searches for records, based on their first and last names, if sql finds the data then the second form comes out, which has lots of textboxes, to update the 'searched'information. And when I click the submit button of the second form , it does nothing, and even if I have syntax or whatever errors I have put on condition if(isset($_POST['submit'])), they end up being disregarded (no error messages will come up), after clicking the submit button, it just goes back to the page's original state, when it has to update the record I have searched for that was just edited. What exactly is the mistake on this part?

class.php - .php file that contains the operations for sql

```
<? php

$months = array('January',
               'February', 
                  'March',
                  'April',
                    'May',
                   'June', 
                   'July',
                 'August', 
              'September', 
                'October',
               'November', 
               'December');

class EmployeeProfile {


    public
    function openConnection() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_employee");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to database server";
        }


        return $conn;

    }

    public
    function insert($query) {

        if (mysqli_query($this - > openConnection(), $query) == 1) {
            echo "Profile successfully registered!";
        } else {
            echo "Register failed";
        }

    }

    public
    function display($query) {

        $result = mysqli_query($this - > openConnection(), $query);
        echo "<br><br>";
        if ($result - > num_rows == 1) {
            while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>First Name</b>: ".$row["firstname"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Middle Name</b>: ".$row["middlename"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Last Name: </b>".$row["lastname"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Date of Birth: </b>".$row["dateofbirth"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Age: </b>".$row["age"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>School: </b>".$row["school"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Highest Educational Attainment: </b>".$row["educ"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Year Last Attended: </b>".$row["yearattended"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Skills: </b>".$row["skills"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Previous Company: </b>".$row["prevcompany"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Position: </b>".$row["position"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><b>Date of Employment:</b> ".$row["dateofemployment"]."</td></tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        } else

        {

            echo "Profile not found";
        }

    }

    public
    function edit($query) {

        $result = mysqli_query($this - > openConnection(), $query);

    }

}

?>
```

edit.php - the page itself.

```
<html>
<title> Edit Profile</title>
<body>

<form method="post" action="?" name="searchform">
<center>
<table>
<tr><td>Enter first or last name</td><td><input type = "text" name="search"><td><td><input type = "submit" value="Search" name="search2"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php
include("class.php");
if(isset($_POST['search2'])):

$status = "hidden";
$query = "select * from employee WHERE firstname='".$_POST['search']."' OR lastname='".$_POST['search']."' ";
$emp = new EmployeeProfile();
$emp->openConnection();

$result = mysqli_query($emp->openConnection(), $query);


if($result->num_rows == 1):




?>

<form method="post" action="?" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="updateform">
<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>Edit your profile:</td></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr><td>*Enter first name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter middle name:</td><td><input type="text" name="middlename"></td></tr>
<tr><td>*Enter last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>*Date of Birth:</td><td><select name="month"><?php for($i = 0; $i < count($months); $i++) { echo "<option value=".$months[$i]." >".$months[$i]."</option>" ; }?></select></td>
<td><select  name="days"><?php for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { echo "<option value"."=".$i.">".$i."</option>";  } ?> </select></td>
<td><select  name="year"><?php for($i = 1950; $i <= 2014; $i++) { echo "<option value"."=".$i.">".$i."</option>";  } ?> </select></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>*Age:</td><td><input type="text" name="age"></td></tr>
<tr><td>*School:</td><td><input type="text" name="school"></td></tr>
<tr><td>*Highest Educational Attainment:</td><td><input type="text" name="educ"></td></tr>
<tr><td>*Year Last Attended:</td><td><input type="text" name="yearattended"></td></tr>
<tr><td>*Skill(s):</td><td><input type="text" name="skills"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Previous Company:</td><td><input type="text" name="prevcompany"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Position:</td><td><input type="text" name="position"></td></tr>
<tr><td>*Date of Employment:</td><td><select name="empmonth"><?php for($i = 0; $i < count($months); $i++) { echo "<option value=".$months[$i]." >".$months[$i]."</option>" ; }?></select></td>
<td><select  name="empyear"><?php for($i = 1950; $i <= 2014; $i++) { echo "<option value"."=".$i.">".$i."</option>";  } ?> </select></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"></td></tr>
<tr><td>* - Required</td></tr>
</form>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$dateofbirth = $_POST['month']. " ".$_POST['days']. ", ".$_POST['year'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$school = $_POST['school'];
$educ = $_POST['educ'];
$yearattended = $_POST['yearattended'];
$skills = $_POST['skills'];
$prevcompany = $_POST['prevcompany'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$dateofemployment = $_POST['empmonth']. " ".$_POST['empyear'];

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$usr = $row["firstname"];


$query2 = "UPDATE employee SET firstname='$firstname', middlename='$middlename', lastname='$lastname', dateofbirth='$dateofbirth', age='$age', school='$school',
educ='$educ', yearattended='$yearattended', skills='$skills', prevcompany='$prevcompany', position='$position', dateofemployment='$dateofemployment',
 WHERE firstname='$usr'";

 mysqli_query($emp->openConnection(), $query2);

endif;





else:
echo "Profile not found";
endif;
endif;


?>

</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and I do really think that this line and beyond gets ignored.

This is part of the `edit.php` file that is shown above.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$dateofbirth = $_POST['month']. " ".$_POST['days']. ", ".$_POST['year'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$school = $_POST['school'];
$educ = $_POST['educ'];
$yearattended = $_POST['yearattended'];
$skills = $_POST['skills'];
$prevcompany = $_POST['prevcompany'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$dateofemployment = $_POST['empmonth']. " ".$_POST['empyear'];

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$usr = $row["firstname"];


$query2 = "UPDATE employee SET firstname='$firstname', middlename='$middlename', lastname='$lastname', dateofbirth='$dateofbirth', age='$age', school='$school',
educ='$educ', yearattended='$yearattended', skills='$skills', prevcompany='$prevcompany', position='$position', dateofemployment='$dateofemployment',
 WHERE firstname='$usr'";

mysqli_query($emp->openConnection(), $query2);


endif;
```

Comment: " it just goes back to the page's original state" ---> That must be the form submission

Comment: That if, the second form submit button is clicked, I would've wanted it to update the profile at the sql, but nothing happens and that's it, but I assure you the first form (search, the form with only one textbox and a submit button) works.

Comment: Is this intentional `action="?"`?

Comment: Plus, remove the comma at the end of `dateofemployment='$dateofemployment',` which is most likely the problem. Do `action=""` if you want to use the action as the same page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just followed what my buddy told me, since he's better than me in PHP, so I just followed it.

I think the problem is that "if(isset($_POST['submit'])):" and the code beyond is just ignored, even if I've put intentional syntax errors it does nothing, and no error messages even show up at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried it, but to no avail, the page will just go back to the original state, no records get updated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `action="?"` is fine, as all browsers I've ever tested it with see it as being the current page, I use the shortcut all the time. The only time it's ever caused me issues was inside of ASPX pages where microsofts parsing tool would see it as being the websites root for some reason.

Comment: @scragar Thanks, I've noted it. Yet, `dateofemployment='$dateofemployment',` the erroneous comma should be removed.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant or not, but you've got a lot of `- >` which should probably have no spaces `->` but I'm not 100% certain about that. What does `var_dump($row["firstname"]);` reveal?

Comment: I do not really know what keeps it from not updating the record if i am going to click the second form submit button (the button named Register)

Comment: I can't pinpoint the issue. Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so and see if it yields any errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it shows the first name, which is string 'Divine' (length=6)

but when i put it inside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) condition, nothing gets displayed

Comment: In your `edit.php` your form element is named `name="search"` while you're using `if(isset($_POST['search2']))` yet you have another that's named `search2` - I'm baffled.

Comment: Not quite on topic, but this script is susceptible to SQL injection. Should use prepared queries instead of building a SQL string.

Comment: That 3rd body of code underneath `and I do really think that this line and beyond gets ignored` is that a page on its own, or is that inside another page?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hehe, the name=search is a textbox, and search2 is the submit form, and I  have used the submit button as my basis for isset, if(isset($_POST['search2'])): works well fine, but if(isset($_POST['submit'])): does not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the third body of code tag is just the last condition I have written on edit.php, it's just part of edit.php.

Comment: Well I can't test this and I can't find the reason as to why it's not working. Try hardcoding it to see if the update works. Wish I could help you more, but I can't.

Comment: It's just fine @Fred-ii- I'm still stuck to this problem lol. Im gonna try re-writing maybe the whole edit.php. Thank you by the way.

Comment: You're welcome. Try using braces `{}` instead of `if:` and `endif;` etc. it may be easier. It may be the way your conditional statements are made as.

Comment: That's what I did earlier, because I thought changing them to if: and endif; would have fixed the problem but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are two kinds of errors present.

1. HTML tag order errors, which are extensive
2. Syntax errors.
   `- >` must be `->` to be properly parsed
   `<? php` must be `<?php` to be properly parsed

The syntax errors are present in both files.

Note: the following code contains some debug statements.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
    echo "<p>In myquery.php header </p>";
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //echo "<p>" . var_dump($_POST); . "</p>";
    //echo "<p>" . var_dump($_GET); . "</p>";
?>

<?php
    include("class.php");
?>

    <title> Edit Profile</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo "<p>In myquery.php body</p>";
?>

    <form method="post" action="?" name="searchform">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter first or last name</td>
                <td><input type = "text" name="search"><td>
                <td><input type = "submit" value="Search" name="search2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>


<?php

    echo "<p>about to check _post for search2</p>";

    if(isset($_POST['search2'])):
        echo "<p>found _post for search2</p>";   

        $status = "hidden";
        $query = "select * from employee WHERE firstname='".$_POST['search']."' OR lastname='".$_POST['search']."' ";
        echo "<p>about to open DB</p>";
        $emp = new EmployeeProfile();
        $emp->openConnection();
        echo "<p>about to place find query</p>";            
        $result = mysqli_query($emp->openConnection(), $query);

        echo "<p>about to check for successful query</p>";
        if($result->num_rows == 1):

            echo "<p>successful search query</p>";
?>

            <form method="post" action="?" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="updateform">
                <table>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td>Edit your profile:</td></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr><td>*Enter first name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Enter middle name:</td><td><input type="text" name="middlename"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>*Enter last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>*Date of Birth:</td><td><select name="month"><?php for($i = 0; $i < count($months); $i++) { echo "<option value=".$months[$i]." >".$months[$i]."</option>" ; }?></select></td>
                    <td><select  name="days"><?php for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { echo "<option value"."=".$i.">".$i."</option>";  } ?> </select></td>
                    <td><select  name="year"><?php for($i = 1950; $i <= 2014; $i++) { echo "<option value"."=".$i.">".$i."</option>";  } ?> </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>*Age:</td><td><input type="text" name="age"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>*School:</td><td><input type="text" name="school"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>*Highest Educational Attainment:</td><td><input type="text" name="educ"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>*Year Last Attended:</td><td><input type="text" name="yearattended"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>*Skill(s):</td><td><input type="text" name="skills"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Previous Company:</td><td><input type="text" name="prevcompany"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Position:</td><td><input type="text" name="position"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>*Date of Employment:</td><td><select name="empmonth"><?php for($i = 0; $i < count($months); $i++) { echo "<option value=".$months[$i]." >".$months[$i]."</option>" ; }?></select></td>
                    <td><select  name="empyear"><?php for($i = 1950; $i <= 2014; $i++) { echo "<option value"."=".$i.">".$i."</option>";  } ?> </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>* - Required</td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>

<?php
            echo "<p>about to check for submit second form</p>";

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])):

                echo "<p>found submit for second form</p>";

                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $dateofbirth = $_POST['month']. " ".$_POST['days']. ", ".$_POST['year'];
                $age = $_POST['age'];
                $school = $_POST['school'];
                $educ = $_POST['educ'];
                $yearattended = $_POST['yearattended'];
                $skills = $_POST['skills'];
                $prevcompany = $_POST['prevcompany'];
                $position = $_POST['position'];
                $dateofemployment = $_POST['empmonth']. " ".$_POST['empyear'];

                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $usr = $row["firstname"];


                $query2 = 
                    "UPDATE employee 
                    SET firstname='$firstname', 
                        middlename='$middlename', 
                        lastname='$lastname', 
                        dateofbirth='$dateofbirth', 
                        age='$age', 
                        school='$school',
                        educ='$educ', 
                        yearattended='$yearattended', 
                        skills='$skills', 
                        prevcompany='$prevcompany', 
                        position='$position', 
                        dateofemployment='$dateofemployment',
                    WHERE firstname='$usr'";

                echo "<p>about to update DB</p>";

                mysqli_query($emp->openConnection(), $query2);
            endif;
        else:
            echo "<p>search query failed</p>";

            echo "Profile not found";
        endif;
    endif;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Thank you for this, but I cannot still try this out as I'm going somewhere, will check your revision for sure! Thank you again!!! You made my code readable!

Comment: @user3628778 The answer is from user3629249 actually, I just cleaned up some formatting. Don't forget to give him an upvote!

Comment: I have tried executing the improved code but it still does not update the edited record, this is kind of absurd now.

Comment: I may have no choice but to redirect to another page after clicking the second submit form.